# how to implemy https (ssl ) with tomcat aes and node js

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services

I am trying to implement https with aws and tomcat. Http is working fine

Already done

```
  1. Open port 443 in security group
  2.Created .keystore file
  keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

3.added below is server.xml file

```
   <Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="25"
port="8443" keystoreFile="/Users/loiane/.keystore" keystorePass="password"
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https"
secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

and after that rebooted also. But still facing same .
please suggest me

Comment: What error are you facing?

Comment: while in browser i used with https i m getting This site can’t provide a secure connection

51.*.*.* sent an invalid response.

Comment: You opened port `443` in the AWS security group, but you are listening on port `8443` in your configuration.